# Add extra column in Google Form using Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am trying to create a Google Form connected to a Spreadsheet with the following functionality:

1. I just want to accept Email Responses
2. After accepting Email Response, add an extra column with user ID
3. Email the person with his user ID from the form.

I have no clue about how to go about it, but while I'm posting this question, I'm reading the developers section for Google-apps-script.  I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option when creating a Form to automatically collect the user's username (email address).  It will be recorded as the second submission value, timestamp being first.

If you create a Google Apps Script on the submission spreadsheet and create an onFormSubmit trigger, you can create a function that adds all of the responses to the body of an email and uses MailApp.sendEmail() to send the submissions.

Or, the user has an option to have their responses emailed to them on submission.  They just need to check it.

I'm sorry if this isn't what you were looking for but I wasn't sure what you meant by just wanting to accept email responses.  I don't think there's a way to submit a form other than filling out the embedded form?